# A Good Database Design for E-Mail or Private Message

Tags: database-design

For now, I'm working with message system for my site. The message is used to send messages between member of the site. It can also be used to send a friendship invitation, etc. However, I haven't found a good database design for it. I want the message system to use a **thread style**, just like e-mail. But since I'm not an expert with complex database design, I cannot figure how to do so.

So far here is my design,

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  message_id            BIGINT      PRIMARY KEY,
  message_date_time     TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT NOW(),
  message_subject       TEXT,
  message_body          TEXT,
  message_attachment    TEXT, -- path to attachment folder
  message_sender_id     INT, -- FK to table user
  message_sender_status INT, -- 0 = deleted by sender, 1=default (can be seen on sender outbox)
);
```

and another table...

```
CREATE TABLE message_recipients (
  message_id               BIGINT, -- FK to table messages
  message_recipient_id     INT,    -- FK to table user
  message_recipient_status INT,    -- 0=deleted from recipient inbox, 1=new message, 2=read
);
```

I believe I need another table to store the link between message, thats' why I need these

```
CREATE TABLE message_reply (
  message_id        BIGINT, -- FK to table messages
  message_to_reply  BIGINT, -- FK to table messages
);
```

But those tables only make me hard to query and handle on my PHP page.
I only want the user can observe the source e-mail and the reply (like GMAIL or Facebook's Wall)...
Any better advice?

> ### Additional description
>
> I want
>   the message can be sent to many
>   recipient. But once it sent, it cannot
>   be modified. Let's say I sent a
>   message to X, Y, and Z. When X reply,
>   there will be a message from X in my
>   inbox. And if Z reply, there will be a
>   message from Z in my inbox, with same
>   subject with X (e.g. RE: subject of my
>   first mail). When I choose X's
>   message, there will be X's message,
>   followed by my first message. If I
>   choose to sent X a reply, X will
>   receive a message contains my reply,
>   her reply, and my first message.
>   Whether I reply Z or Z reply me again,
>   that will be another matter from X. X
>   cannot see what Z wrote and on the
>   other hand, Z cannot see the
>   conversation between me and X.
>   Complicated isn't it? That's why i on
>   the verge of death because of these
>   matter. Sigh -_-,

Thank you
Tony

Answer (score 1):

if the message is sent by 1 person and only received by 1 person, you dont need a link-table you juse do:

```
message
- message_id
- recipient_id -> links to user.user_id
- sender_id -> links to user.user_id

user
- userid
```

if the message can be a reply to another message, just add a field to the message itself to say that it is a reply to:

```
message
- parent_id -> message.message_id, or null if it isn't a reply.
```

this is a pretty easy setup, it isn't optimal if you are going to extend it a lot but this works pretty simple.

Comment: What happens if a sender puts a message into his trash?  With this database design, the message will be placed into the trash for both the sender and the recipient.  Would there be a need to keep two records of a message, one for the sender and the other for the recipient?  Or perhaps a joined table to keep track of this?